# Alternate to copying app.config settings to web.config?

Tags: asp.net, configuration

I am working on a class library that uses Microsoft enteprise library logging application block. I have some settings in my app.config file.

Now, when a developer uses this library in a web applications, they have to copy entire config sections and appsettings part from the app.config to the web.config.

Is there something which can be done to bypass this step and makes it easier for developers to use my library without manual copy of all those settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try putting the repeated sections in an external config file, adding that file as a reference to the web.config project, and then referencing it in both the app.config & the web.config.

Comment: I thought of going this way but is this the best and cleanest approach? I assume there must be some better ways to handle this

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Library has a visual config editor that you can use to load your web.config.
You can choose the settings you want and have them persisted to this file. Personally, I would not use Enterprise Library unless I had no choice. Simply too much glop code and overhead.

Comment: Point is I am creating a library, and have all the settings in the app.config. Now when a developer uses my libary, application will look for the current settings in the application and not in the library's app.config. Now every time developer has to copy those settings from library's  app.config to app's web.config.